# GD Visual C++ 2008

Tags: visual-c++, linker, gd

Is there some step by step guide to link GD library ( www.libgd.org ) to the project in MSVS? 
Because I'm getting linker-errors when trying to compile my project:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gdImageCreateFromJpeg referenced in function _main
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have forgotten to add the GD library DLL to the Project.